# pandas: unable to remove the second column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am attempting to remove some columns from a DataFrame. I can successfully remove the first column but when I attempt to remove the second, it failed and I am not sure why.

Code:

[image: df.drop(columns=["StockName", "DirectorName"])]

I have also attempted with the same outcome:

```
df.drop(["StockName", "DirectorName"], 1)
```

Error Message:
[image: screenshot of the error message]

Comment: What is `print (df.columns.tolist())` ? Maybe need remove traling whitespaces `df.columns = df.columns.str.strip()`

Answer (score 0):

[@jezrael](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2901002/jezrael) was correct with the df.columns = df.columns.str.strip(). This worked successfully.
I will check to see if there are any excess spaces in the orignal file the DataFrame was created from.

TY all